# Reducing file size of scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to reduce the file size of a scatter plot. My code looks like:

```
plt.scatter(a1,b1)
plt.savefig('test.ps')
```

where a1,b1 are arrays of size 400,000 or so, and it gives a file size of 7.8MB.

I have tried adding

```
plt.rcParams['path.simplify'] = True
```

before this chunk of code, but the file is still 7.8MB. Is this an issue with how it saves as a ".ps" file or another issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to use `plot` instead of `scatter` (you can still produce scatter plots using `plot` by using the `'o'` argument), and use the `rasterized` keyword argument, like so:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1,b1 = np.random.randn(400000,2).T #mock data of similar size to yours
plt.plot(a1,b1,'o',rasterized=True)
plt.savefig("test.ps")
```

This should significantly reduce the size of the output file. The text and line art will remain vector, only the points are rasterized, so it is a nice compromise.

Depending on what you're looking to achieve, however, it might be better to histogram your data and plot that instead (e.g. `pyplot.hist2d` or `pyplot.hexbin`).

Comment: But this solution loses all advantages of using a vector-based format like PostScript in the first place, doesn't it?

Comment: This approach only rasterizes the points, the text and line art stay vector. It's true that you can't arbitrarily zoom, but I guess there has to be some trade-off between the information content of the graphic and its size in memory. For me, this is often a useful compromise.

Comment: Thank you. This got my PDF size from 15MB to 4MB

Comment: I love this approach for scatter plots! It's indeed a great compromise

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using e.g. `hexbin` -- I particularly like this when you have a dense collection of points, since it better indicates where your data is concentrated. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

x = np.random.normal(size=40000)
y = np.random.normal(size=40000)

pl.figure()

pl.subplot(121)
pl.scatter(x, y)
pl.xlim(-4,4)
pl.ylim(-4,4)

pl.subplot(122)
pl.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=40)
pl.xlim(-4,4)
pl.ylim(-4,4)
```

[image]

From the left figure, I would have concluded that the distribution of points between `x,y = {-3,3}` is roughly equal, which clearly is not the case.

(http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html)