# Matplotlib: optimize vector image output, remove hidden vectors data

Tags: matplotlib, vector-graphics

Assume I have a very big Matplotlib scatterplot with **overlapping points**.

Is there a way to ask Matplotlib to optimize ('compress')  the plot (e.g. during `savefig`), so to not export vectors which are invisible (overlapped by others).

My current EPS/SVG/PDF-`savefig` is very big.

I can solve this by preprocessing the input data, however level of overlapping also depends on the plot properties (e.g. size of the marks etc).

If Matplotlib cannot do this, are there other tools which can **optimize vector graphics** (open source/free tools,so not the Adobe suite).

Tx.

Comment: I think that the answer is no. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974576/reducing-file-size-of-scatter-plot/39977232#39977232 for a similar question

Comment: Rasterizing your data points is definitively a good option. You won't have to remove any points and you will still be able to use alpha.